# ASP.NET core indentity error: Entity type 'AppUserLogin' is defined with a single key property, but 2 values were passed to the 'DbSet.Find' method

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity, openiddict

I override Identity classes:

```
 [Table("Roles")]
    public partial class AppRole : IdentityRole<int, AppUserRole, AppRoleClaim>
    {
    }
    [Table("RoleClaims")]
    public partial class AppRoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim<int>
    {
    }
    [Table("Users")]
    public partial class AppUser : IdentityUser<int, AppUserClaim, AppUserRole, AppUserLogin>
    {       
    }
    [Table("UserClaims")]
    public partial class AppUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int>
    {
    }
    [Table("UserLogins")]
    public partial class AppUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int>
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
    [Table("UserRoles")]
    public partial class AppUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int>
    {
    }
    [Table("UserTokens")]
    public partial class AppUserToken : IdentityUserToken<int>
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class AppRoleManager : RoleManager<AppRole>
    {
        public AppRoleManager(IRoleStore<AppRole> store, IEnumerable<IRoleValidator<AppRole>> roleValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber errors, ILogger<RoleManager<AppRole>> logger, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) : base(store, roleValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, logger, contextAccessor)
        {
        }
    }
    public class AppRoleStore : RoleStore<AppRole, AppDbContext, int, AppUserRole, AppRoleClaim>
    {
        public AppRoleStore(AppDbContext context, IdentityErrorDescriber describer = null) : base(context, describer)
        {
        }

        protected override AppRoleClaim CreateRoleClaim(AppRole role, Claim claim)
        {
            return new AppRoleClaim(role, claim);
        }
    }
    public class AppSignInManager : SignInManager<AppUser>
    {
        public AppSignInManager(UserManager<AppUser> userManager, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<AppUser> claimsFactory, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, ILogger<SignInManager<AppUser>> logger) : base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger)
        {
        }
    }
    public class AppUserManager : UserManager<AppUser>
    {
        public AppUserManager(IUserStore<AppUser> store, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, IPasswordHasher<AppUser> passwordHasher, IEnumerable<IUserValidator<AppUser>> userValidators, IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<AppUser>> passwordValidators, ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber errors, IServiceProvider services, ILogger<UserManager<AppUser>> logger) : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger)
        {
            var LoginStore = Store;
        }
    }
    public class AppUserStore : UserStore<AppUser, AppRole, AppDbContext, int, AppUserClaim, AppUserRole, AppUserLogin, AppUserToken, AppRoleClaim>
    {
        public AppUserStore(AppDbContext context, IdentityErrorDescriber describer = null) : base(context, describer)
        {
        }

        protected override AppUserClaim CreateUserClaim(AppUser user, Claim claim)
        {
            return new AppUserClaim(user, claim);
        }

        protected override AppUserLogin CreateUserLogin(AppUser user, UserLoginInfo login)
        {
            return new AppUserLogin(user, login);
        }

        protected override AppUserRole CreateUserRole(AppUser user, AppRole role)
        {
            return new AppUserRole(user, role);
        }

        protected override AppUserToken CreateUserToken(AppUser user, string loginProvider, string name, string value)
        {
            return new AppUserToken(user, loginProvider, name, value);
        }
    }
```

and I want to use external login for Google, but when I call `await UserManager.FindByLoginAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey);` I get error:

> Entity type 'AppUserLogin' is defined with a single key property, but
>   2 values were passed to the 'DbSet.Find' method.

I am following tutorials [openiddict](https://github.com/openiddict) and [ASP.NET Core and Angular 2](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781786465689.do), but I am pretty sure this error does not have anything with this 2 tutorials. I think my code is not working, because I change TKey for UserLogins table: `public partial class AppUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int>`. Even searching for [is defined with a single key property](https://www.google.si/search?espv=2&q=%22is%20defined%20with%20a%20single%20key%20property%22&oq=%22is%20defined%20with%20a%20single%20key%20property%22&gs_l=serp.3...18388.18388.0.20736.1.1.0.0.0.0.85.85.1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.0.0.V7Jahzz_8YE) results nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution is in `DbContext.OnModelCreating` method.
I change from:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<AppUserLogin>(entity =>
    {
        entity
        .HasKey(u => u.Id);
        entity.Property(p => p.Id)
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    });
```

to:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<AppUserLogin>(entity =>
    {
        entity
        .HasKey(u => u.Id);
        entity.Property(p => p.Id)
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        entity
        .HasKey(u => new { u.LoginProvider, u.ProviderKey });
    });
```

and it works.

Comment: You dob't really want to modify your `ModelSnapshot`, instead insert only the new `HasKey` call into `MyDbContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)`.